# How to find the first (earliest timestamp that day) file in a folder for e certain date?

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I have a function that searches a specific folder, looks for the latest date of files created with a certain prefix and returns the first (earliest) file written that day.

```
import os

def find_earliest_file(prefix, folder):
    """
    Searches the specified folder for files with the specified prefix, and returns the earliest file (by timestamp) 
    for the newest date.
    """
    newest_date = None
    earliest_file = None
    
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if file.startswith(prefix):
            timestamp = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder, file))
            file_date = timestamp.date()
            
            if newest_date is None or file_date > newest_date:
                newest_date = file_date
                earliest_file = file
            elif file_date == newest_date and timestamp < os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder, earliest_file)):
                earliest_file = file
    
    return earliest_file
```

However, I get the following error and I cannot understand why...

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'date'. Cell In[48], line 12 in newest_file
file_date = timestamp.date()

How can file_date be a float?

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime):

> The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the time module).

Use the `time` module to manipulate it, as recommended.
You can use `gmtime` or `localtime` to convert respectively in UTC and local time.

```py
import time

time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder, file)))
# or
time.localtime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder, file)))
```